# How does using C# and C++ together with Unity affect efficiency?

Tags: unity, c#, c++

I'm new to game dev and I'm looking to use Unity to create a phone game that will utilize neural networking. Obviously, putting neural networks in a mobile game presents a serious performance concern, so I'd like to use C++ rather than C# for the best performance possible. I've researched a bit and it seems like there are a couple of ways I could do this, but I think I would always have to build a layer of C# between Unity and the logic, which would reduce performance. So my question is, is it worth it? Will it actually be faster to write the logic in C++, or is the extra layer of code likely to bog things down too much?

Comment: The only way to get a surefire answer to "is X faster than Y" is to write a test and profile it on your target hardware. There are too many variables in exactly what you might be doing and how you might be doing it, so Internet hearsay just won't be a reliable guide here. That said, you may want to consider using the Unity job system, which uses a subset of C# that can compile to very efficient native code, with all the marshalling handled for you so you don't have to write your own interface layer.

Comment: [Unity also has some first-party neural network features](https://unity.com/products/machine-learning-agents) that may be worth evaluating to see if they can cover your use cases and whether you get adequate performance out of the box, before you try to roll your own solution.

Comment: Checking out those neural network features now. This looks neat! Not sure yet what all it can do, but I think this may be as good of an answer as there is for this question. Thanks!